# Layer plots and annotations in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a figure that shows how a number of KPIs have trended over three periods with respect to two indicators.

I've managed to get most of the way there plotting the KPIs (each a different colour) for the three periods with the axes measuring the indicators, however I still need a way to highlight which period is which for each KPI. My intention is to have a number (1, 2, or 3) inside each of the marker bubbles, however I'm not able to get the layering right to keep it neat.

Here's what it looks like at the moment

[Current attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Mvd.png)

The issue I'm having is that even though the annotations are inside the initial loop, the chart renders with all the annotations on top of the plots. I'm fine with having elements on top of one another, but I want the annotations on each marker on the same layer as the marker so that if three points are stacked, only the top marker and number will be visible.

I could have the annotations floating, but I plan to produce a number of these for different business areas so I want a format that will be stay relatively neat with different data.

The data is structured in a df called 'ps3_trends' under the following columns:

['KPI', 'Sat', 'Rank', 'S']

with KPI the index and S = {1, 2, 3} indicating the period.

The code I'm using to plot and annotate looks like:

```
for i in kpis:

    x = ps3_trends[ps3_trends.index == i].Sat
    y = ps3_trends[ps3_trends.index == i].Rank
    l = ps3_trends[ps3_trends.index == i].S

    plt.plot(x, y, marker = 'o', markersize = 18

    for xs, ys, ls in zip(x, y, l):
        plt.annotate(ls, xy = (xs, ys), xytext = (0,0),
                     textcoords = 'offset points', ha = 'center',
                     va = 'center', color = 'white', fontweight = 'bold',
                     fontsize = '12)
```

Wondering if there is a way to have matplotlib generate the plots while simultaneously annotating them to keep the layers?

Comment: you can manually set zorder  in your plot commands to increase as you go, this way the first one gets drawn first, and then the next and so on.

Comment: Many thanks @evamicur - this has worked relatively well!